# custom styles using ck editor

Tags: ckeditor

I was wondering if it is possible to make a custom style in  using the first-line css psuedo class?

I tried to modify the supplied .js file but had not luck.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must add that to your stylesheet, it's not possible to specify pseudo classes inline.